# Is it possible to have 2 languages simultaneously activated for spell-checking text cells in Mathematica 11?

Tags: front-end, spellchecker

I like the spell-checking introduced in Mathematica 11. However I don't see how to activate 2 dictionaries simultaneously, say, English + Russian?

I found that current language for entire notebook can be changed through Edit | Preferences | User Interface Settings.

It seems also that active language for a text cell can also be reset through Right-click on the cell's right boundary, Options | Formatting Options | DefaultNaturalLanguage. But only one language can be selected at a moment.

Comment: +1 Say: English, Portuguese and French...

Comment: @P.Fonseca: English + Russian is easier case since Russian uses different alphabet. Cyrillic letters have codepoints different form latin ones even for those letters which look simllarly.

Comment: I understand. But I don't mind misspelling something on one language, because the word exists on another language that is "activated" at the same time. While we wait for language auto-detection (everything is there... right?), or the possibility of setting the spelling a different language on just a piece of the cell (this one might take "longer" to be implemented...), Having more than one dictionary activated would facilitate my life...

Comment: any solutions found?